# Getting the package options as a lua string, and allow arbitrary package options

Tags: luatex, packages, key-value

I am making a lualatex-based class, which will be a thin wrapper around a lua library. I would like to use the `luakeys` package to process my options in lua, and would like to avoid declaring options. My question is two-fold:

1. Can I allow the package I'm writing to accept arbitrary options?
2. How would I retrive the options as a string in lua?

MWE:

```
\ProvidesPackage{MWE}

\RequirePackage{luapackageloader}
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\DeclareOption*{} % I think this is sufficient to allow arbitrary options.. 
\ProcessOptions\relax

\begin{luacode*}
    texio.write_nl('VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV')
    texio.write_nl(token.get_macro('@nameuse{opt@MWE.sty}'))  -- isn't this
    texio.write_nl(token.get_macro('@classoptionslist'))       -- isnt this

    local luakeys = require('luakeys')
    local kv = luakeys.parse(token.get_macro('???')) --is there a command, or way I can get the raw options
                                                                   --  that were passed to this package as a str ?
    texio.write_nl('VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV')
    luakeys.print(kv)
\end{luacode*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro you want to access for the raw options is `\@raw@opt@<file>.<ext>`. And to prevent LaTeX from throwing errors on unknown options you should do `\let\@unprocessedoptions\relax`.

So this here is what you want:

```
\ProvidesPackage{MWE}

\RequirePackage{luapackageloader}
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
  local luakeys = require('luakeys')
  local kv= luakeys.parse(token.get_macro('@raw@opt@MWE.sty'))
  luakeys.print(kv)
\end{luacode*}
\AtEndOfPackage{\let\@unprocessedoptions\relax}% don't throw errors for option

\endinput
```

And using this driver file:

```
\RequirePackage[my=opt, opt=key]{MWE}
\stop
```

You'll get the following on the terminal output:

```
{
  ['opt'] = 'key',
  ['my'] = 'opt',
}
```

Caveat: Your options still need to survive one `\edef` assignment without breaking due to the way LaTeX handles options historically.